# Azure Data Lake gen2 (Data Lake Storage) Access Control on container level with Managed Identity

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-managed-identity

I try to script grant role to Azure Data Lake gen2. The is no issue with adding this for Service Account:

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzResource -Name $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
$datafactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -Name $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
$contributorRoleDefinition = Get-AzRoleDefinition -Scope $storageAccount.ResourceId -Name 'Contributor'

$dataFactoryRole = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $storageAccount.ResourceId -ObjectId $datafactory.Identity.PrincipalId -RoleDefinitionId $contributorRoleDefinition.Id
if(!$dataFactoryRole)
{
    New-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $storageAccount.ResourceId -ObjectId $datafactory.Identity.PrincipalId -RoleDefinitionId $contributorRoleDefinition.Id
    Write-Host "Access to blob storage for data factory was granted"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Access to blob storage for data factory has already been granted"
}
```

The issue is I want to grand permission on container level - not service account level. Above scrip generate on container level: ***Parent resource (inherited)*** but what is need is: ***This resource***.

I can do it through portal, but is not valid solution for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grand permission on container level, please refer to the following script

```
Connect-AzAccount

$container=Get-AzRmStorageContainer -Name $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $containerName

$datafactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -Name <> -ResourceGroupName <>

$role=Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name "Storage Blob Data Reader"

$dataFactoryRole = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $container.Id -ObjectId $datafactory.Identity.PrincipalId -RoleDefinitionId $role.Id
if(!$dataFactoryRole)
{
    New-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $container.Id -ObjectId $datafactory.Identity.PrincipalId -RoleDefinitionId $role.Id
    Write-Host "Access to blob storage for data factory was granted"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Access to blob storage for data factory has already been granted"
}
```

[image]

Besides, please note that if you want to access Azure Blob with AD auth, you need to use these roles: **Storage Blob Data Contributor**, **Storage Blob Data Reader** and **Storage Blob Data Owner**. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#managed-identity)